# What should stationery include?

Tags: print-design, client-relations, print-production

I am trying to organize my client folders and one of them is stationery.

I am hoping to hear some advice on what you think stationery includes. Would it be only business cards, letterheads, and envelopes, or also labels, stickers, pocket folders, notepads, etc.?

And how about e-signatures, flyers and brochures? Would that be separate from stationery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my world stationery is paper, sheets and pads, and envelopes. Letterheads? Yes.

Stickers, post its, little pads and labels are not stationery. As a category they are just office supplies or consumables. Nothing else in your list is stationery.

Everything in your list should be included in a branding package. The things which should have your brand on them are listed here, but they aren't stationery.

Answer (score 6):

[Stationery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationery) items will typically fall under the 'office supplies' category, that is items intended to be processed in-house before being handed out to clients. This includes items intended to be written on (notepads, block notes, labels, stickers) or printed on (letterheads, invoices, envelopes, forms). Business cards are also stationery.

Flyers and brochures would be excluded from this list and could be more likely called [marketing collaterals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marketing_collateral), as these are ready made prints with no further writing/printing needed on top of the original print and will generally provide a more substantial content, not just basic contact information.

Answer (score 3):

**Stationery** consists of anything which is designed to be used internally with the company branding - business cards, folders, letterheads, envelopes, invoices, purchase orders, post-its, note pads. Essentially what an *employee* would use when doing their job.

**Marketing materials** or *collateral pieces* would encompass anything designed to be read/seen by the *consumer* to entice a sale - brochures, fliers, sales letters, posters, banner ads, landing pages, etc.

**Brand giveaways** would encompass anything designed to further the recognition of the brand without any direct purpose for either the employee or consumer (in terms of company functions) - i.e. pens, stickers, cups, mousepads, etc.